# Android schedule repeating alarm from service

Tags: android, android-service, android-alarms

I am trying to schedule repeating alarms in Android. The first alarm works fine but the second is never fired. I know that my mistake is in the service class. I tried to reschedule it in the Wakeful receiver and works fine but I need to do it before the service stops itself.

```
// Alarm fired from the activity and works!


private void startPingRepeatingAlarm() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PingReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Log.i("Ping WakefulReceiver", "Starting alarm @ " + new Date().toString());
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        am.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000, pendingIntent);
    } else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            am.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000, pendingIntent);
        } else {
            am.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000, pendingIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

The receiver:

```
public class enter code herePingReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    public PingReceiver() {
    }

        @Oventer code hereerride
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.i("Ping WakefulReceiver", "Received alarm intent @ " + new Date().toString());
            startWakefulService(context,new Intent(context, PingService1.class));
        }
    }
```

And the service inner code:

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        final Intent in = intent;

        new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                Log.i("Ping WakefulReceiver", "Rescheduling alarm @ " + new Date().toString());
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), PingService1.class);
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, intent, 0);

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    alarmMgr.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000, pendingIntent);
                } else {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                        alarmMgr.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000, pendingIntent);
                    } else {
                        alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000, pendingIntent);
                    }
                }

                PingReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(in);
                stopSelf();
            }
        }.execute();
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If this is an `IntentService`, get rid of the `AsyncTask` and move all that logic into `onHandleIntent()`. Also note that you might not be able to set an alarm that frequently on Android 5.1 and higher.

Comment: It is a standard service not an IntentService. I know about the limitation of Doze mode...

Comment: OK, so, why not make it an `IntentService`?

Comment: It's not working. I think the problem is that IntentService run it's own worker thread and the alarmManager needs the main thread.

Comment: `AlarmManager` does not require the main application thread.